# Selenium webdriver - how do I hit the X button to stop the pageload?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chrome-web-driver

Is there a command in the WebDriver API to stop the page load?  I have a situation where the page takes forever to load, even though all the stuff I want is there.  I just want to simulate manually hitting the X button next to the URL bar in order to stop the page loading.

Comment: Why do you want to test a page that hasn't fully loaded?

Comment: Did you google how to use Selenium to stop the page load?

Comment: @aimbire It's a pretty common request actually. On some sites there are some long running scripts that have little to nothing to do with the content on the site so having to wait for them to finish for automation to proceed is a pain and a waste of time.

Comment: @JeffC yes, I've spent several hours googling how to solve this problem.  `window.stop()` doesn't work for me - not sure why. It seems to stop the page, but it doesn't cause the .get(URL) command from leadfoot (TheIntern) to successfully return.

Comment: Where is the X button?

Comment: Please share the URL

Comment: @JeffC do you know the answer to my question?  If not, what are you really contributing?

Comment: @jononomo Your question does not meet the standards of SO. I'm contributing by pointing you to links that explain that in more detail. You need to fix your question before it gets downvoted and closed.

Comment: @JeffC I guess we disagree -- but go ahead and edit to contribute to my question if you'd like.

Comment: Sorry jonomo, but your question not only doesn't belong here, it also goes against the whole idea of testing. If the page takes too long to load, maybe it needs rework.

There's a very easy way to do what you want, and even a better way that might not involve manipulating the browser in anyway, but it's so bad that I wouldn't advise at all.

Comment: @aimbire respectfully I ask you not to comment if you have nothing to contribute

Comment: I did contribute, you are just being obnoxious now. Feel free to keep doing the wrong way then.

Comment: @jononomo It's your job to edit your question and add details to bring it up to SO standards, not mine. If you are unwilling to do that, perhaps you shouldn't ask questions here.

Comment: @JeffC This question is not out-of-line.  I'm sorry you're bothered by it, but I will continue to use and contribute to the site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript executor to stop the window or send keys Keys.ESCAPE.

See :https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/is-it-possible-to-stop-page-loading-on-the-browser-using-selenium-web-driver for more details